# string::length returns false value?

Tags: c++, string, string-length

```
string str = "abcdef";
cout << str.length() << endl; //6
cout << str.length() - 7 << endl; //4294967295
```

I don't understand why str.length() - 7 returned 4294967295 instead of -1.

Could you help me to explain this?

Comment: [See this](https://ideone.com/Rrb8Rf) to give insight on the answers given to you.  You see that the answer **is** `-1`, just that you are seeing -1 in a different form (unsigned instead of signed).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - an unsigned type can't have a value of `-1`.  However, when it is assigned a negative value, the value is converted using modulo arithmetic.   The result can, but doesn't necessarily, have the same bitwise representation as a signed integral variable of the same size with value `-1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of [`str.length()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) is `size_t`:

> **size_t** length() const noexcept;

you can think about it as an `unsigned int` for this case.

The unsigned integer underflows when it gets to a negative value, wraps around and goes to other extreme, causing *you*, to see in your system 4294967295.

4294967295 (2^32 - 1) corresponds to the maximum value of a 32-bit unsigned type - which is consistent with a fair few 32-bit implementations. Moreover `size_t` can be, but is *not* required to be, a 32-bit type.

Comment: Might want to note that the value `4294967295` corresponds to the maximum value of a 32-bit unsigned type - which is consistent with a fair few 32-bit implementations.   And that `size_t` can be, but is not required to be, a 32-bit type.

Answer (score 8):

`str.length()` returns a `size_t`, which is unsigned. This unsigned result wraps around and that is why you get 4294967295 instead of -1.

Comment: ...Because the unsigned number wraps around... That is an important part you forgot to mention.